# Hide scrollbar on scollable element

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to hide the scrollbar in all browsers (Safari, Chrome Firefox, IE10 and IE11, Edge and Mobile Safari)

The HTML looks like this:

```
<section class="no-scroll">
    <ol>
        <li class="s">1</li>
        <li class="c">c</li>
        ....
    </ol>
</section>
```

Its a horizontal slider. Now, I have the following to hide it

```
.no-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-moz-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-o-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-google-ms-scrollbar {display:none;}
.no-scroll::-khtml-scrollbar {display:none;}

section {
    ...
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bbthutyt/5/)

This seems to work in Safari and Chrome but not in IE and Firefox. Furthermore, I'm getting more and more doubts about this approach being the right solution. Can someone give me advice on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow: hidden; on the body tag like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 body {
     overflow:hidden;
  }
 </style>
```

The code above hides both horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

If you want to hide only the vertical scrollbar, use overflow-y:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
      overflow-y:hidden;
  }
  </style>
```

And if you want to hide only the horizontal scrollbar, use overflow-x:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
      overflow-x:hidden;
  }
  </style>
```

If you want to hide particular element scrollbar, then use identifiers like id or class in place of body as shown below

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .no-scroll{
              overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Note that I need to be able to scroll, but without the scrollbar

Comment: this is a trick to somewhat overlap scrollbar with an overlapping div which doesn't have any scroll bars